# Has Trump authorized the construction of 115 miles of border wall?

Tags: donald-trump, mexican-border-wall

Accordign to [Twitter](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor)

> @realDonaldTrump I am in the Oval Office & just gave out a 115 mile
> long contract for another large section of the Wall in Texas. We are
> already building and renovating many miles of Wall, some complete.
> Democrats must end Shutdown and finish funding. Billions of Dollars, &
> lives, will be saved!

Is this true? I can't find any real verification. If so, is it a new contract (and where is the funding coming from?), or maybe a renewal of some existing contract, or a maintenance contract?

Comment: Related on Politics.SE: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/35062/how-much-of-trumps-border-wall-has-been-completed-so-far

Comment: Great cross-link, thanks (+1). So, somewhere between 2 and 36 miles already built, with 2 being the accepted answer.  This would bring  it to a whopping 117 miles, if it is new build

Comment: Also note the key word "renovating" in Trump's tweet. Much of the activity is in replacing old wall built many years ago out of spare parts with new purpose-built wall. Still counts IMHO, as the new wall is much harder to climb over.

Comment: I wonder if [the army will build it](https://twitter.com/realdonaldtrump/status/1072471575956504576?lang=en)

Comment: Wow! Donald Trump uses 115 mile long contracts!  They must be very very detailed.  So how long is the section of wall supposed to be?

Comment: This article a day before Trump's tweet mentions "replace 115 miles of border wall" https://www.newsmax.com/politics/borderwall-government-shutdown-funding/2018/12/23/id/895594/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one else answered, here is what I found.

Cancada's global news is [reporting](https://globalnews.ca/news/4793962/donald-trump-border-wall-550-miles/)

> With a fight over border wall funding keeping the U.S. government shut
>   down, President Donald Trump said Tuesday that construction is set to
>   start on “probably the biggest section” of the wall in Texas next
>   month.
>
> Speaking to reporters on Christmas morning, Trump said the federal
>   government yesterday handed out a contract to build 115 miles (about
>   185 kilometres) of wall, which represents about a fifth of the total
>   500 to 550 miles (805 to 885 kilometres) he expects to see constructed
>   along the U.S.-Mexico border.
>
> He hopes to have all 550 miles built by November 2020, when the next
>   U.S. election rolls around.

However, althogu it says

> the federal government yesterday handed out a contract to build 115 miles (about 185 kilometres) of wall

I can't find to whom the contract was awarded.

Comment: This is just a news article that reports what Trump said.  It doesn’t address whether it’s true or not.

Comment: Agreed, which is why I didn't award the answer. But no one else has posted anything, so here's the little which I could find